# Salt state to enable re-run systemd service

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to craft a salt state file to simply ensure-enabled and re-run my one-shot service. I thought it would be nice to re-run if any of the dependent files changed, but honestly this is simple enough and the short-lived service is almost never going to be running when I want to update.

Current attempt:

```
myown-systemd-service-unit-file:
...

myown-systemd-service-executable-file:
...

myown-service:
  systemd.force_reload:
    - name: myown
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - myown-systemd-service-unit-file
      - myown-systemd-service-executable-file
```

is failing at with errror:

```
----------
          ID: myown-service
    Function: systemd.force_reload
        Name: myown
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'systemd.force_reload' was not found in SLS 'something.myown'
              Reason: 'systemd.force_reload' is not available.
     Changes:
```

By `enable`, I mean to have the equivalent of this CLI call be applied:

```
sudo systemctl enable myown.service
```

Relevant docs: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.systemd_service.html#module-salt.modules.systemd_service

Answer (score 1):

The `systemd_service` module is an *execution module*, and the [syntax](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) to use such modules is slightly different. The state declaration you are using is for *state modules*. Also, the example from the documentation points to use of `service.force_reload` rather than `systemd.force_reload`.

```
salt '*' service.force_reload <service name>
```

Considering all this, the below example restarts and enables `myown` service when the service unit file changes.

```yaml
myown-service:
  module.run:
  - service.restart:
    - name: myown
    onchanges:
    - file: myown-systemd-service-unit-file
  - service.enable:
    - name: myown
```

Note that I've used `restart` instead of `force_reload` to bounce the service. Also I'm using `onchanges` for `file` module as you haven't shown how you manage the two files. You can use the appropriate module and state IDs.

Comment: Ah I now get failure with comment: `Module function myown-service is not available`.

Comment: The [module.run syntax](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) has seen some changes between versions. I've used the new syntax.

Comment: I looks like I'm operating at a version before `3005`, but also that the documentation is unclear whether there is forward-support and that just legacy support is dropped after version `3005`.

Comment: I'm using Salt version 3003.3 and this syntax works fine for me. Try setting the `use_superseded` directive in minion configuration.